# Movable Type or Wordpress plugin to publish content from other blogs automatically on my site?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, publish, movabletype

I'd like to build a plugin where a WordPress user (or other platform like Movable Type) can install and publish automatically in his/her blog and at the same time to my website..

This is something like Facebook already does...
I have no clue where to start with or if there is already any pay service I can use instead...
If you have any documentation to suggest I'll appreciate it...

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Movable Type plugin called [Reblog](https://github.com/movabletype/mt-plugin-reblog/)?  We use this plugin extensively to republish content from other websites that's exposed in an RSS or Atom feed.

Answer (score 0):

Movable Type and [Melody](http://openmelody.org) can do this, depending on how you want to do it. In some cases, it'd require a plugin, but if you manage both sites with Movable Type or Melody, you can have an entry on one site appear on the main page of another.

Answer (score 0):

ReBlog is a very old, but still nice solution that I've used myself in the early 2000 years.

Alternatives to it, are the following other solutions:

1) for movable type v4.x and v5.x
http://en.magicvox.net/archive/2010/04110959/

2) for movable type v4.x (not tested on v5.x)
https://github.com/danwolfgang/movabletype-crossposter

There is one more plugin, but that works with v2.x which is very old.

Comment: When you say Reblog is very old, what do you mean?  The last update for it was a week before you made your comment: https://github.com/movabletype/mt-plugin-reblog/commit/ddd489db69aaa76743fdf9882cedba104d11218a.

Comment: I mean that the technology has been on for a lot of time and there are some newer alternatives to it.

Comment: The movabletype-crossposter plugin was written by Arvind Satyanarayan in 2007 or earlier.  Certainly Dan Wolfgang has updated it, but the last commit was a year ago.

The AtomSync Trac repository on MagicVox.net goes 404.

No criticism intended to these developers, but these projects aren't as up-to-date as Reblog.

Comment: IMHO it is not very important when the project has been updated, but its efficiency and how well it fits to ones goal. This doesn't mean that the reBlog plugin is not good. Glad to hear that you've also got it working with v5.x

Answer (score -1):

This is just as simple as having that second site subscribe to and watch for updates to the first's RSS feed. Whenever it sees an update, it sucks it down and re-publishes it.

Comment: Why the spurious, no comment down voting? This is not what down voting is for. From the bylaws "Whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect, vote it down!" You don't use down voting just to say no.